# Is there a standard place to install software that doesn't follow the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard?

Tags: linux, unix

Let's say I'm building and installing some third-party software called `foo`. I want headers in `/usr/local/include/foo`, shareable read-only data in `/usr/local/share/foo`, and so on. But let's say `foo` insists on being difficult and wants me to pick a directory `PREFIX` and install stuff in `${PREFIX}/include` and `${PREFIX}/share` and so on. If I choose `PREFIX=/usr/local` then it might clobber some existing files in `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/local/share`, and so on. Are there best practices for where `PREFIX` should be?

Comment: There is always the [FSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what [`/opt`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-3.12.html) is for.  Make a directory inside `/opt` for the self-contained software package.  You'll have to add `/opt/*/bin` to your `PATH` manually.

Comment: What exactly are "add-on application software packages"? If, hypothetically, `foo` were the main server daemon running on my machine, would it still be appropriate to install it in `/opt/foo`, just because it breaks the rules?

Comment: "Add-on" means software that is provided by someone other than the operating system vendor.  Yes, your hypothetical example shows exactly how /opt is meant to be used.  Software that installs into /opt is a bit rare in the Linux community, since your distro's package manager does a fine job of managing files throughout the filesystem hierarchy.    However, it's not wrong, and is in fact quite common practice with Unix flavors that don't have such capable package managers as Linux.

Comment: Fair enough, then.

Comment: `/opt/$VENDOR/$PACKAGE/$VERSION/<pseudoroot filesystem>` seems to be a pretty good way to do it.